# Automatically get data from a specific workbook among other workbooks with similar name

Tags: excel

I have a folder which contains workbooks, and everyday a new file is uploaded to this folder.

I need to find a way where (another workbook I have) TES_Workbook automatically gathers data from the newest file in the folder.

For example TES_Workbook should get data from AKS_20210930 and not the other files, because of the current date.

All the names of the files starts with AKS_20210901, AKS_20210902, AKS20210903 etc.

Any who can guide me in the above question?

Comment: You'll need to code something in VBA in order to achieve this.

Comment: I found the below, but dont know if I just can use this, 


Dim sDate as String

    sDate = Format(now, "ddmmyyyy")
    sFile = sPath & "AKS_" & sDate & ".CSV"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with Power Query.

- Data tab in the ribbon > Get Data > From File > From Folder
- Navigate to your folder, click Open, click Transform Data
- Filter the extension column to csv
- Filter the Date Created column to Is Latest
- When you only have the latest file click the double arrows in the Content column

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Jody, 
It fixed my problem :)